# Why this React conditional rendering has issue?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

Props data is fetched by the parent element.
results a delay to fetch them
I checked for empty or null props and the console log is OK :

```
import React from 'react'
import styles from '../articles.css'
const TeamNfo = props => {
    const team = props.teamData
    // console.log( team)

    return !team || team.length < 1
        ? <p>Loading ...</p>
        : <>
            {console.log(team)}
            {/* {
                city: "New Jersey"
                count: 0
                description: "At vero eos et accusamus et ."
                id: 3
                logo: "nets.png"
                name: "Nets"
                poll: "false"
                stats: Array(1)
                    0: {wins: 23, defeats: 12}
            } */}
            <div className={ styles.articleTeamHeader }>         
                <div className={ styles.left }
                    styles= {{
                        background: `url('images/teams/${ team.logo })`
                }}>
                </div>

                <div className={ styles.right}>
                    <div>
                        <span> { props.team.city } { props.team.name } </span>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </>
}
export default TeamNfo
```

returns this error message on the screen:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'city' of undefined
```

Is it still loading the return with undefined props?

Comment: the error itself explain to you that props.team is undefined. so you need to use team.city instead of props.team.city

Comment: In addition to using the wrong variable, You are printing `Loading` to screen when teams has zero elements which does not necessarily mean it's loading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`team` is a local variable. Use `team.city` or `props.teamData.city`, e.g.:

```
<span> { team.city } { team.name } </span>
// or
<span> { props.teamData.city } { props.teamData.name } </span>
```

Comment: LooooL :D  tnx bro